# I need to create a session variable in ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I have the following code with two session variables defined

```
      <% 
      Set rsusers = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
sql = "SELECT * FROM LE_LoginMaster where login='" & login & "'"

Session("emplname") = emplname
Session("divrec") = divrec
      %>
```

But when I try to use the session variables that I defined in another ASP page the variable values don't show up

```
<%=Session("divrec")%></br>
<%=Session("emplname")%>
```

Comment: What's `emplname` and `diverc` - where do you define then and where assign values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code I cannot see where you are assigning `emplname` or `divrec` a value. Try to `response.write` those values on that page to make sure they even exist before trying to access them from another page.

You could also check to make sure you are using the same session on those pages by `<%=Session.SessionID%>`. If those are different on the two pages, then somehow your session is getting lost.

Comment: Your advice really helped out!